# How to make stroke-width scale with svg width but not with height?

Tags: svg, path, stroke

I need strokes to scale with width but not with height.

This is the closest I've come to a solution:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="50">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-width="5" stroke="blue" d="
            M 0,0 L 1,1
            M 0,1 L 1,0
        "/>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

This lets me change the height without affecting the stroke width, but also I need the strokes to scale when the entire svg is scaled. The problem is that I can't make the strokes scalable again. I've tried using percentages, but they are relative to the diagonal size.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the SVG to get larger when you increase the `width` or `height`, but the stroke width should only be proportional to the width?  There is no way to do that with plain SVG elements and properties.  It would require some supplementary javascript.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau That is what I want, yes. So there isn't any way to stretch the coordinates before the lines are drawn?
I'm making flags, mainly for a website, and I'm making them the same ratio. Most flags allow for this, but the widths of diagonals are proportional to the height of the flag. It would be a lot of work if I want to change the standard ratio in the future, so if there is no way to do this with raw SVG I might use PHP to calculate the coordinates instead.

Comment: I'm still not 100% confident we are talking about the same thing.  Or why it would be necessary. 
 Can you update your question with mockup screenshots showing the behaviour you are after?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Should I post the example as png or svg? I'm a new user and not sure if it would be considered clutter. I found two half-solutions that are adequate for my use cases but imperfect, but I'm not sure whether to answer my own question or add it to my question. If I can adjust the `viewBox` with css I'll have a more complete solution.

Comment: I meant a PNG.  I'm trying understand what you want the behaviour to be.  Re viebox and CSS: you can't modify the viewBox using CSS.  It is not one of the styleable properties of SVG.